# How to create loop in custom page, and get id from url into this loop?

Tags: loop

I need to create loop in **wordpress** custom page and this loop will display a content for post from custom category.

I create this page and get **ID** for this post, now i just need to make loop get this post from url **ID**.

[image: This is the custom page and post url]

Answer (score 0):

basically what you want to do is get the id from `$_GET['id']`

then you can use the WP_Query

```
<?php
    wp_reset_postdata();
    $args = array(
        'category' => $_GET['id'],
        'order'      => 'DESC',
    );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
//do your stuff here......................
endwhile; endif;
        ?>
```

here `$_GET['id']` will get all the posts from category

If `$_GET['id']` is a post ID and you have to retrive all the posts using that specific posts category then simply get the category id from that post by using

```
$category_detail=get_the_category( $_GET['id'] );
```

and then you can use the query like:

```
 $args = array(
    'category' => $category_detail,
    'order'      => 'DESC',
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

hope this helps

Comment: thank you very much, what i need is get post from url id

Comment: to query post `$post_temp = get_post( $_GET['id'] ); 
    $title = $post_temp->post_title;`

Comment: No it is inside in my file i just paste it here outside